# Switching between Databases at will in PHP MS SQL Server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database

I'm making a page to modify values in databases, but I need to be able to switch databases (SQL Sever) at will (they are exact copies but serve different purposes), and I want to do it in PHP, right now it is a conexion.php with a function that is included in every page, but I have been asked to make a page where I can select the DB (kinda like a settings page), and I can't figure a way to tackle this.

I would have to get all the Database names, add them to a list box then submit them, I would need the SQL query to select all the database names and the php for the db change, here is the connection file:

```
<?php
session_start();
function conex()
{
    $db = "DFSistemasMercietDBTest";
    $server = "dfsistemas";
    $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>$db, "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"Sa123456");
    $conex = sqlsrv_connect($server, $connectionInfo);
    if($conex === false)
    {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    return $conex;
}   
?>
```

The function is called through the pages with:

```
include('conexion.php');
$conex=conex();
```

Comment: This sounds like a nightmare to maintain to me. Why use different databases all the time? You can get a list of databases from sys.databases.

Comment: It doesn't look like you have put much effort into it yet. Please at least attempt the solve the problem, then we can assist you along the way.

Comment: It's not my duty to mantain the DB's, there are various DB's because each one represents a store, the tables are all from an enterprise software but my page will do some things the software doesn't have in a simply way.

The issue is that I don't know how to tackle it, do I use sessions? Can I modify the connection file from outside? It's more guidance rather than fixing a problem.

Comment: The way I've seen it done is to have a configuration file for the web application which contains all the connection information for each DB, then on the landing page you pick which DB you want from a drop down menu.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I want to do, the thing is, I don't know how to do it